# Can i use different variable name with @resouce

Tags: java, spring, annotations

It might be very basic question but having NPE so want to make sure

do i have to use same resource name for variable or can be different when injected?

```
@Resource(name='foo')
private X foo;
```

or can be

```
@Resource(name='foo')

private X fooxx;
```

i am using second case where instance name is different from resource name but getting NPE

Comment: That should work fine. Just don't forget to create setter. Additional reading: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncjk.html

Answer (score 1):

Comment is correct this should work .... ensure the types are correct but the issue is probably something else. 
According to [Spring docs on @Resource](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)...

> 3.9.5 @Resource
>   Spring also supports injection using the JSR-250 @Resource annotation on fields or bean property setter methods. This is a common pattern in Java EE 5 and 6, for example in JSF 1.2 managed beans or JAX-WS 2.0 endpoints. Spring supports this pattern for Spring-managed objects as well.
>   @Resource takes a name attribute, and by default Spring interprets that value as the bean name to be injected. In other words, it follows by-name semantics, as demonstrated in this example:

```
public class SimpleMovieLister {

  private MovieFinder movieFinder;

  @Resource(name="myMovieFinder")
  public void setMovieFinder(MovieFinder movieFinder) {
      this.movieFinder = movieFinder;
  }
}
```

> If no name is specified explicitly, the default name is derived from the field name or setter method. In case of a field, it takes the field name; in case of a setter method, it takes the bean property name. So the following example is going to have the bean with name "movieFinder" injected into its setter method: